# Is it possible to add an int to a pair?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

Is this a valid operation in c and c++?

`daysgoneby += months[monthindex].day;`

basically add a field from a lookup table to an int (in this case its an int to an int so it seems valid).

where daysgoneby is of type int, and `months[monthindex].day` refers to this table below.

If not why? and how might one circumvent this to use the type int located in the table.

```
struct Monthpairs                       // Fields for month & day lookup
{
    const char* mon;                    // Months
    int day;                            // Days
};

Monthpairs months[] =                   // Lookup table for months & day
{
    {"Jan", 31},
    {"Feb", 28},
    {"Mar", 31},
    {"Apr", 30},
    {"May", 31},
    {"Jun", 30},
    {"Jul", 31},
    {"Aug", 31},
    {"Sep", 30},
    {"Oct", 31},
    {"Nov", 30},
    {"Dec", 31},
};
```

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: That's fine, `months[monthindex].day` is an `int` too. No problem.

Comment: *edit* response to comment that was deleted. srry!

Comment: You're not adding an int to a pair, you're adding an int to an int which is as natural as can be. Unless your question was how to do the same thing without dereferencing the `day` part of the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is perfectly fine, in the end the `day` field in your lookup-table is just an `int` as well.

Regarding the title of your question, while using a specific field in your pair is fine (as long as the types are correct for the operator/function), you can't add to the pair itself because its type doesn't match what the operator expects.